# Why didn't Tobi use Kamui when Minato used Rasengan?

Tags: naruto

During the fight between Minato Namikaze and Tobi (in episode 248 *The Fourth Hokage's Death Match* of the *Naruto: Shippuden* anime, or chapter 502 and 503 of the manga), Minato **escaped** from Tobi's Kamui, despite having been **caught** in the technique unexpectedly.

[image]

3 minutes and a few seconds later into the episode, the two ran towards each other. At an extremely close distance, Minato pulled off a **Rasengan**. Considering the bright aura and the sound it makes, I'm pretty sure Tobi noticed it.

[image]

Tobi let the kunai that Minato had thrown pass through him. So instead of using Kamui to let Minato phase through him, why did Tobi keep going? Minato had already escaped from Kamui once, and that was when he was caught unexpectedly.

Comment: I have no idea, but your current question doesn't have any close vote. What I have been doing so far is to make the question look better. I don't read Naruto so I can't really tell whether this question is subjective or not. However, my **uninformed** impression of this question is that it is a bit strange to use a skill when you know your opponent can avoid it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In chapter 502 from page 8, Tobi fought with Minato. As [nhahtdh commented](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18813/why-didnt-tobi-use-kamui-when-minato-used-rasengan#comment24074_18813), there is no reason to use the same jutsu twice when the opponent can avoid it.

The image below shows Minato's inner thoughts moments before they clashed against each other in the second image.

[image: one on one]

In the second image you posted above, if you take a closer look

[image: both attacking]

You can see the kunai passing through Tobi. If you are not aware, Tobi was actually using Kamui to let the kunai pass through him. However, to attack, Tobi had to solidify his body. Tobi couldn't attack and defend at the same time with Kamui. Correct me if I am wrong here.

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, Tobi touched Minato and was going to attack. I don't know what jutsu he was going to use, but Tobi was confident that he would win, so his whole body was solid and he was not using Kamui.

[image: Boom]

[Hiraishin Level 2](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_%E2%80%94_Second_Step) was faster than Tobi's attack, and Boom. Rasengan.

So the reasons why Tobi did not use Kamui to let Minato's attack pass through him:

- Using the same jutsu twice against an elite shinobi is foolish, unless one has well-grounded confidence that it will work, or has another motive.
- Tobi was confident that he was going to win this fight, as you can see on third picture.
- He was unaware of [Hiraishin Level 2](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_%E2%80%94_Second_Step). As you can see, he was surprise when Minato jumped to the kunai.

Comment: Hiraishin level 2. Not Hiraishin

Comment: IIRC all the Hiraishin Jutsu used by Minato used Marked but stationary Kunai but that Kunai was moving.

Comment: Another reason would be that Flying Raijin level 2 and above is faster than any dojutsu can read. Plus, Obito didn't even expect Minato to use the kunai he evaded nor use Rasengan again.